# SQLite MYSQL character encoding

Tags: iphone, sqlite, nsstring

I have a strange situation where the following code works however XCode warns it is deprecated...

```
NSString *col1 = [NSString stringWithCString:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 0)];
```

However as that is the deprecated method if I set an encoding the string comes out wrong!  I have tried all the encodings but none work!

```
NSString *col1 = [NSString stringWithCString:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 0) encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would have expected satire's suggestion to have worked, however here is the Cocoa version of what I use:

If you are dealing with utf16

```
int len = sqlite3_column_bytes16(compiledStatement, col) / 2;
unichar *chars = (unichar*)sqlite3_column_text16(compiledStatement, col);
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithCharacters:chars length:len];
```

If you are using utf8

```
int len = sqlite3_column_bytes(compiledStatement, col);
char *chars = (char*)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, col);
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:chars length:len];
```

Answer (score 0):

try 
NSString *col1 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 0)];

if your database coded with utf8

Comment: Afraid not, this returns anything with special characters in as (null) when NSLogging it out.  How do I check the database coding?

Comment: Simple tool for manage SQLite tables is a javascript Firefox plugin called SQLite Manager, you can open your database from your application bundle whit that. To check your database encoding see the DBSettings tab.

Comment: use `printf("%s", (char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 0));` to see the char value witch returning from datebase

Comment: The printf stops after the first few entries

Answer (score 0):

First check that entry in the database contaoins Same Roman Words or not .

`NSString *strtemp = [NSString stringWithCString:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 0)];
strtemp=[strtemp stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding];`

NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding will definately work.I have face same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it works for me for UTF8 encoding

```
char *chars = (char*)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, col);
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithCString:chars encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```