# iOS SQLite encoding issue: can't retrieve string because of "ï¿½" character

Tags: ios, sqlite, encoding

I can't get a certain string by usual

```
    NSString *retrievedString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text (compiledStatement, 0)];
```

statement. Any other strings are printed just fine. When I try to NSLog that string, its printed as "(null)". How do I resolve that issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This seems similar to the problem in [SQLite MYSQL character encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5258007/161332)

My response there was to try

```
int len = sqlite3_column_bytes(compiledStatement, col);
char *chars = (char*)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, col);
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:chars length:len];
```

which may help.  The only other thing I can think of is that perhaps your text is just not UTF8 and is in some other encoding?